# passenger friendly error page log file location

Tags: apache2, phusion-passenger

I am trying to troubleshoot a rails application running on apache2 and passenger. I tried looking into the global log file at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` however I don't see anything useful. What I did was enable friendly error pages on passenger and this gives me the information I need. However, I would like to know where exactly it pulls these error messages from so I can look at them directly

Answer (score 0):

I had to uncomment `LogLevel info` in my apache config. D'oh